# Datastore and models undefined on Postgresql with Sails v1

Tags: postgresql, sails.js

I got the following error on sails V1 after upgrading from V0.12.

```
      adapterMethodName: 'find',
      modelIdentity: 'users',
      raw: 
       { UsageError: Could not run select() because of 2 problems:
    ------------------------------------------------------
    • "datastore" is required, but it was not defined.
    • "models" is required, but it was not defined.
    ------------------------------------------------------

Please adjust your usage and try again.
```

I added some prints in the node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js file in registerDatastore to see if my settings are correct in sails, and the models and datastores are passed correctly. I then added a print in the find function and found that the datastores and modelDefinitions arrays are empty. Not sure where they should be populated, I can assign them myself, but I don't want to mess around in the node_modules. I also tried starting a new Sails V1 app en just migrating my changes to it, with the same results. Any suggestions would be appreciated?

***Here are some version specific details***:

```
 : node        : v9.10.1
 : engine (v8) : 6.2.414.46-node.23
 : openssl     : 1.0.2o
```

***My config***:

**sails.config.datastores**:

```
  default: {
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    user: 'xxx',
    password: 'xxx',
    database: 'xxx',
    ssl: false,
  },
```

**sails.config.globals**:

```
module.exports.globals = {

  _: require('@sailshq/lodash'),

  async: require('async'),

  models: true,

  sails: true,

  services: true,

  adapters: true,

};
```

**sails.config.env.development**:

```
 datastores: {
   default: {
      adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432,
      user: 'xxx',
      password: 'xxx',
      database: 'xxx',
      ssl: false,
    },
  },
```

Some verbose prints on startup:

```
verbo: grunt hook loaded successfully. (8ms)
     : Loading hook: orm
     : Loading the app's models and any custom adapters...
     : Loading app models...
     : Loading app adapters...
     : Loading hook: sockets
verbo: Loading adapter (`sails-postgresql`) from this app's `node_modules/` directory...
     : Starting ORM...
     : Registering model `file_types` in Waterline
.
.
.
.
verbo: orm hook loaded successfully. (1036ms)
```

**package.json**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@sailshq/connect-redis": "^3.2.1",
    "@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3",
    "@sailshq/socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "ajv": "^6.4.0",
    "async": "2.0.1",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3",
    "bugsnag": "^2.3.1",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "connect-redis": "^3.3.3",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "gifsicle": "^3.0.4",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "machinepack-emailaddresses": "^0.4.0",
    "machinepack-redis": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "rsmq": "^0.8.3",
    "sails": "^1.0.0",
    "sails-hook-grunt": "^3.1.0",
    "sails-hook-orm": "^2.0.0-16",
    "sails-hook-sockets": "^1.4.0",
    "sails-postgresql": "^1.0.0",
    "sharp": "^0.20.1",
    "soap": "^0.24.0",
    "socket.io-redis": "^5.2.0",
    "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.17",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "uuid-validate": "0.0.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fix for this issue on master branch but it is not tagged and pushed to npm yet ([Bug 277](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-postgresql/pull/277))

Apparently, one of your models is not configured correctly and sails is not telling you what it is because of the bug.

So, to get around this issue, you should install the fixed commit of `sails-postgresql` from the github url, start sails to see what the issue is, fix it, and then reinstall your regular sails-postgresql version again.

You can install fixed master commit via yarn:
`yarn add https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-postgresql.git#1ead0f407231aa2139a73fc65e5ded608418a92d --save`

Via npm:
`npm install https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-postgresql.git#1ead0f407231aa2139a73fc65e5ded608418a92d --save`